# GIT: How to commit a change with .git folder already inside a working directory to that repository via batch command?

Tags: git, batch-file, commit, working-directory

Here's my current repository, and made it as my working directory.

[image]

As you can see, there's a BAT file, "backup.cmd" with the contents shown below:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe" add . && "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe" commit -am "Periodic Backup %DATE%"
```

Now, I am setting a task scheduler in Windows 7 that allows me to weekly create a backup to this repository. However, there's a problem when it comes to commiting changes in any of these files.

The problem is that, by running the BAT file, Git is unable to commit changes. The cause for it unable to commit changes is because of the ".git" folder residing in the working directory.

I have tried to use ".gitignore" and ".git/info/exclude" to ignore/exclude the ".git" directory, but it still fails to let me commit the changes. I do not know any other methods of ignoring/excluding  the ".git" directory.

Can anyone help me on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure this is why it's failing? Git ignores the `.git` directory by default.

Comment: @hammar Proof. http://i.imgur.com/e0huO.png

Comment: @hammar This error happens when you try starting the task of running "backup.cmd" via Task Scheduler.

Comment: If you look at that picture you posted it's trying to run the git commands in `C:\Windows\system32`. That's your problem. You need to make your batch file `cd` to the working directory.

Comment: Thank you! I do admit, I never realized that until you pointed it out. Running from Task Scheduler now worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @hammar, I now know what my problem is.

Because the Task Scheduler was running the batch file in a location where there's no GIT commands available to the command prompt (which means it was running the commands by its default location (C:\Windows\system32)), it would output an error saying that ".git" doesn't exists.

The fix is to change the location to the actual GIT repository, and then re-execute the batch commands, so that way the Task Scheduler knows what to do with them.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of staging the directory each time (`git add .`), use `git add -A` to stage all new files.  The presence of the `.git` directory indicates that the repository is already initialized, and does not need to be staged during each batch run.  `git add -A` stages all changed and new files, which seems to be what you want, but you might prefer `git add -u`.

Comment: Tried your method, both "git add -u" and "git add -A" failed when starting the batch file via Task Scheduler. Proof: http://i.imgur.com/lhQZu.png